# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Handle Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, handleerror

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I want to use my custom handle error attribute. Therefor I wrote this class :

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error Occured");
        }
    }
```

And I have added attribute at controller level :

```
[MyHandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(Exception),View="ErroView")]
    public class MeetingController : Controller
    {....}
```

When an error occures in controller, it can't be handled. If I press F5 in debugger after error, ErrorView is displayed. But `Debug.WriteLine("Error Occured");` line never works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`OnException` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.onexception%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is `virtual` but because you don't have the `override` modifier there you are hiding and not overriding this method. So your custom method won't get called by the MVC framework.

To correct this you just need to `override` the method:

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);
        Debug.WriteLine("Error Occured");
    }
}
```